# Moment Estimation for a Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

> For a random sample $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ from a uniform $[0,\theta]$ distribution, with pdf
>
> $$f(x;\theta) = \left\{ \begin{array} \ \frac{1}{\theta} & 0\le x \le\theta,\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{array}\right.$$
>
> a) investigate whether the resulting estimator $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.
>
> b) Derive the standard error of $\hat\theta$

So, I have approached this question, starting with getting moment estimator $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$, which gives me $\hat \theta = 2 \bar X$, from here I think that the question would be so much easier if they ask for $k$ value that makes this unbiased (we know it's 2), but how do we generally investigate $a)$?

And for $b),$ Do I just take square root of variance of $\hat\theta$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The 'general method' is to set the sample mean $\bar X$ equal to the population mean $\theta/2$ to get the method of moments estimator (MME) $\hat \theta = 2\bar X$ of $\theta.$

(2) Yes. By definition, the standard error of the estimator $\hat \theta$ is $SD(\hat \theta) = \sqrt{Var(\hat \theta)}.$

Notes: The multiple $(n+1)/n$ of the maximum $X_{(n)}$ of the data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is also an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, and it has a
smaller variance than the MME. Maybe showing that is a later
exercise in your text.

It is not difficult to find the PDFs of these two estimators and thus to derive these relationships analytically (see
[this Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128755/)),
but the following simple simulation (using the [sampling method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635250/)) in R provides a preview
of the results (for $n = 5$ and $\theta = 10$).

Notice that the distribution
of the MME is roughly normal after averaging only five uniform observations. Even though the second estimator is less variable, the [mode](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648168/) of its PDF lies to
the right of $\theta = 10.$

```
 m = 10^5;  n = 5;  th = 10
 x = runif(m*n, 0, th)
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # each row is sample of size n
 a = rowMeans(DTA)        # vector of m means
 b = apply(DTA, 1, max)   # vector of m maximums
 mme = 2*a;  mean(mme);  sd(mme)
 ## 10.01064              # approx. of E(MME) = 10 (unbiased) 
 ## 2.588815              # approx. of SE(MME)
 est2 = ((n+1)/n)*b;  mean(est2);  sd(est2)
 ## 10.00017              # approx. of E(EST2) = 10 (unbiased)
 ## 1.69188               # indicates SE(EST2) < SE(MME)
```

[image]